# Midnight as 24:00 not 00:00 in Excel

Tags: excel, time, vba

This isn't explicitly a programming question but maybe I can get around it with VBA.

I have some times I'm working with that go over midnight and Excel is not displaying them because they would be 'negative values'.
Eg: 00:30 - 23:30 (or 12:30 am - 11:30pm). This is causing many errors.

Is there a way to get around this? I've tried changing the format to [hh]:mm:ss and this doesn't help. I've also changed the time format to 1904 but this causes problems with other errors I'm using.

Comment: You could use a if statement to test if the first is less than the second than add one day or 1 to the first then subtract.  `=IF(A1<B1,A1+1,A1)-B1`

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing calculations With times going cross midnight, you need to add a date, thereby Excel will know which timestamp that is the latest.

i.e.

00:30 - 23:30 does not work

jan 02 2000 00:30 - jan 01 2000 23:30 Works fine

use the actual date or whatever date is suitable, the important thing is just that 00:30 is the day after 23:30

or if you have the from-time in b2 and the to-time in c2:

```
if(c2>b2;c2;c2+1)-b2
```

change if and ; to whatever Excel wants in your locale

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm going to use the latter approach :)

Comment: Actually just to clarify, what does the +1 do? Is it adding a day or hour?

Comment: Why retype the `-b2`.  It is not needed `if(c2>b2;c2;c2+1) -b2` will work without the extra stress on the fingers.

Comment: @micuzzo it is adding full day